# Naturally sort a flat array without preserving original keys

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, reindex, natural-sort

Is there any way for `natsort()` to also change the indexes?

I.e.

```
$array = array('IMG0.png', 'img12.png', 'img10.png', 'img2.png', 'img1.png', 'IMG3.png');
natsort($array);

Array
(
    [0] => IMG0.png
    [4] => img1.png
    [3] => img2.png
    [5] => IMG3.png
    [2] => img10.png
    [1] => img12.png
)
```

But I want:

```
$array = array('IMG0.png', 'img12.png', 'img10.png', 'img2.png', 'img1.png', 'IMG3.png');
natsort($array);

Array
(
    [0] => IMG0.png
    [1] => img1.png
    [2] => img2.png
    [3] => IMG3.png
    [4] => img10.png
    [5] => img12.png
)
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) will effectively reindex any array passed to it with sequential integer keys. So you just need to do:

```
natsort($array);
$array = array_values($array);
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `sort()` with its natural sorting flag.  This way you don't need to bother calling `array_values()` to re-index.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/P9qS5))

```
sort($array, SORT_NATURAL);
var_export($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `array_values` to get the values of the array and break the key-value association:

```php
<?php

$tarray = array('IMG0.png', 'img12.png', 'img10.png', 'img2.png', 'img1.png', 'IMG3.png');
natsort($tarray);
$tarray = array_values($tarray);

?>
```

So:

```php
<?php

$tarray = array('IMG0.png', 'img12.png', 'img10.png', 'img2.png', 'img1.png', 'IMG3.png');
print_r($tarray);
natsort($tarray);
$tarray = array_values($tarray);
print_r($tarray);

?>
```

yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => IMG0.png
    [1] => img12.png
    [2] => img10.png
    [3] => img2.png
    [4] => img1.png
    [5] => IMG3.png
)
Array
(
    [0] => IMG0.png
    [1] => IMG3.png
    [2] => img1.png
    [3] => img2.png
    [4] => img10.png
    [5] => img12.png
)
```

See [comment on natsort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php#32612).